# Trouble with handleSubmit for a form. (React/Mongoose/Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, event-handling

I am doing a small project in React, Mongoose and Expressjs and when I hit submit on the form, nothing happens. I am also getting this error in my express server:

> { description:
> { ValidatorError: Path `description` is required.

**Blog component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from '@reach/router'
import { getBlogs } from '../Api.jsx'
import AddBlog from '../components/AddBlog.jsx'


export default class Blog extends Component {
  state = {
    blogs: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getBlogs()
      .then(res => {
          // console.log(res.data)
          this.setState({blogs: res.data})
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      })
  }
  
  newPostedBlog = addedNewBlog => {
    this.setState(currentState => {
      return {
        blogs: [addedNewBlog, ...currentState.blogs]
      };
    });
  };
  
  render() {
      const {blogs} = this.state;
        return (
      <div className="blog-container">
        <Link to={`/blog/new`}>
        <button className="create-blog-button">Create new blog</button>
        </Link>
          <p className="blog-header">Blogs</p>
            <ul className="blog-ul">
             {blogs.map((blog) => (
               <li key={blog._id}>
                 <Link to={`/blog/${blog._id}`} className="link-to-single-blog">
                 <div className="blog-title">{new Date(blog.title).toLocaleDateString()}</div>
                 </Link>
                 <div className="blog-description">{blog.description}</div>
                 <div className="diary-btn-container">
                 <button className='diary-btn' onClick={this.handleClick}> Diary </button>
                 </div>
               </li>
            ))}
          </ul> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**AddBlog component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { postBlog } from '../Api.jsx';

export default class AddBlog extends Component {
  state = {
    description: ""
  }
  
  handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({ description: event.target.value})

  }
  
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { description } = this.state;
    const { newPostedBlog } = this.props;
    postBlog(description).then(newBlog => {
      newPostedBlog(newBlog)
      this.setState({description: ""})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            <div className="description-box-container">
            <textarea onChange={this.handleChange}
                      placeholder="Say what's on your mind..." 
                      className="description-box"
                      rows="30"
                      cols="120"
                      type="text"
                      id="body"
                      value={this.state.description}>
            </textarea>
            </div>
            
          </label>
          <div className="submit-thoughts-btn-container">
          <button type='submit' className="submit-thoughts-btn"> Submit your thoughts! </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )    
  }
}
```

**Back-end POST controller:**

```
exports.postBlog = (req, res) => {
    const newBlog = new Blog();
    newBlog.description = req.body.description;
    
    newBlog.save().then(newBlog => {
        res.send(newBlog)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

**Blog model:**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    //npm package to force unique key as mongoose doesn't provide this
    const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
    
    // schema to define key types for blog schema
    const blogsSchema = new Schema({
        
        title: {
            
           type: Date,
           required: true,
           default: Date.now,
           unique: true
       
        },
        
        description: {
            
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }
})
```

**Api.jsx:**

```
export const postBlog = (id, title, description) => {
  const baseURL = 'https://f2f1c0aaf7de41d4bc57354de1d10938.vfs.cloud9.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/blog/new'
  return axios.post(baseURL, { title, description}).then(res => {
    return res.data.blog;
  })
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry if I have missed anything, let me know. :) Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show your `Blog` model?

Comment: Also if you can show your `postBlog` function in `Api.jsx`

Comment: Please share what `req.body` looks like. Error message suggests that in the `Blog` model schema, `description` field is required but when you submit the form, it doesn't contains the value for the `description` field.

Comment: could you log the value received in your `postBlog in Api.jsx';`

Comment: I have added the blog and Post Blog function. Looking at the other comments now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your submit function you are calling `postBlog(description)` with one param, however in your `postBlog` function definition in `Api.jsx` you receive 3 params which causes the 2nd and 3rd param to be undefined hence `description` is undefined when you pass it to your post.

To fix this you need to remove the other params from your function definition or pass them along when calling your function.

PS keep in mind that `title` is also required as per your `Blog` model and in your current implementation you pass undefined for `title` as well.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand why it would be undefined, thank you. Sorry I'm a junior and it's my first week. I'm still learning! It's giving me 'newPostedBlog' is not a function. Could you confirm I passed this through props correctly?

Comment: I don't see where you are using `AddBlog` in your `Blog` component, where do you display the `AddBlog ` component?